# What is the Exponent input of Voronoi’s Minkowski Distance?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes, procedural, mathematics, vector

Is the parameter “Exponent” of Minkowski Distance the p value of Minkowski Distance formula? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: P/S: To moderators, sorry if this post doesn't fit this site. Please keep it up for at least a day, I've asked everywhere else and still haven't received an answer. There's a chance someone here has the answer to this.

Comment: Personally, I think there's no problem with this question. it's about understanding, which aids the _use_ of the application. Hopefully someone can scurry into the code and have a look for you. (The exponent seems unlikely to be anything other than`p`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the distance formula is the one you show: If you look it up in the *Blender Reference Manual* for older versions, the formula is given there, in the manual for the current version there are Wikipedia links to the formulas.

Read the *Blender Reference Manual* entry for the *Voronoi Texture* here:

[Voronoi Texture Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.4/render/shader_nodes/textures/voronoi.html)

If you follow the link to the Wikipedia article there, you will find this formula for the *Minkowski distance*:

$$D\left(X,Y\right) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i-y_i|^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$

But of course the exponent ${\frac{1}{p}}$ can be written as

$$D\left(X,Y\right) = \sqrt[p]{\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i-y_i|^p}$$

and that is the formula you have in your question.

Now the **Exponent** which the node is referring to is not the "outer" exponent ${\frac{1}{p}}$, but the "inner" exponent $p$ as you already suspected.

In the old version's manual entry the formula is given directly with the notation using $\frac{1}{p}$, but the description clearly says:

- **Minkowski**

  *A generalized algorithm that can represent all other distance metrics by configuring the Exponent input. This exponent represents $p$ in the Minkowski distance function.*

"A generalized algorithm that can represent all other distance metrics" means, if you for example set $p=1$ you get the *Manhattan* distance, $p=2$ of course gives the *Euclidean* distance and $p\to\infty$ (if you could enter $\infty$ as value) would be *Chebyshev*.

Comment: Thank you! I'm also inclined to believe that $p$ (instead of ${\frac{1}{p}}$) represents the **Exponent** input. Just to add, in the tutorial linked below, the tutor explained that when $p=2$ (not $\frac{1}{p}=2$), Minkowski Distance becomes Euclidean Distance.
https://youtu.be/eutzTEGgLpE?t=629

Comment: @IanAmbrose Yes, I made a few tests with the _Voronoi Texture_ and found it must be $p$, I already edited the answer to make it clear.